# Помогите продолжить последовательность

Tags: c#

Создайте класс StackOfStrings, который может хранить ТОЛЬКО строчки и имеет следующую функциональность:

- Закрытое поле: **data: List**
- Общедоступный метод: **Push(string item): void** помещает элемент в стек
- Общедоступный метод: **Pop(): string** возвращает(удалив) элемент из стека
- Общедоступный метод: **Peek(): string** возвращает (без удаления) последний элемент из стека
- Общедоступный метод: **IsEmpty(): bool** возвращает **true**, если стек пустой, иначе возвращает false

Используйте композицию/делегирование, чтобы использовать список в качестве поля для хранения данных стека

Мои ваяния:

```
class StackOfStrings 
    {
        private List<string> data;

        public StackOfStrings()
        {
            this.data = new List<string>();
        }
        public void Push(string item)
        {
            data.Add(item);
        }
        public string Pop()
        {

        }
        public string Peek(string item)
        {


        }
}
```

Ступор в методах **Pop** и **Peek**

Answer (score 1):

Ну как-то так, наверное:

```
class StackOfStrings
{
    private List<string> data;
    public StackOfStrings()
    {
        this.data = new List<string>();
    }
    public void Push(string item)
    {
        data.Add(item);
    }
    public string Pop()
    {
        if (data.Count() == 0) throw new InvalidOperationException();
        element = data[data.Count() - 1];
        data.RemoveAt(data.Count() - 1);
        return element

    }
    public string Peek(string item)
    {
        if (data.Count() == 0) throw new InvalidOperationException();
        return data[data.Count() - 1];
    }
}
```